# Site does not access and IIS has AppPool started, but needs to stop and start again

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have a problem with my IIS. Each customer has their AppPool, but in some situations that I can't find out, some sites are unable to access. And when accessing the ISS, the AppPool has the status running (started) and only works again, when I click stop and then start.

Has anyone had this problem and/or can help me with this, even to get more log about this possible error.

Comment: Badly written web apps can lock up all threads and lead to issues like that. Debug the hang dumps or use a profiler.

Comment: Check the “Advanced Settings” in the application pool, there is setting for “Idle Time-out”. It means that if there are not requests to the application pool, it will stop and restart again when receiving the next request.
Check the below link,
https://serverfault.com/questions/469199/iis-sites-often-goes-down-and-comes-up-after-app-pool-recycle